# How Can an Erlang Virtual Machine be run as a Daemon?

Tags: erlang

I would like to run Erlang VM as a daemon on a UNIX server, in a non-interactive mode

Answer (score 15):

The simplest thing is to give `erl` the `-detached` flag.

There are however many helpers out there for doing this, check out rebars release handling, erlrc and run_erl.

Answer (score 6):

Also [rebar](https://bitbucket.org/basho/rebar/wiki/Home) can generate a node that can be started as a daemon (with start, stop, restart commands).